# Scrapy: info only visible in text after expanding element

Tags: scrapy

I'm new to scraping and trying to get brokers' name from `http://brokercheck.finra.org`. The html content I want will only be visible after expanding some nodes.

```
import requests
import scrapy

url = brokercheck.finra.org/individual/summary/2713535
r = requests.get(url)
r.text
```

I want to get the broker's name but it is in the tag `//div[@class="namesummary"]`. However, `r.text` don't capture such extent. It is a feature of the website or I can do something to make `r.text` get all the expanded nodes first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render the page in your browser another request is sent to `https://api.brokercheck.finra.org/search/individual/2713535?hl=true&nrows=12&query=&start=0&wt=json`.

In that request you'll find the name. Parse the content with json. Scrapy can't handle dynamic requests that are sent like this.

**EDIT**

I made a test spider that extracts the name, have a look below:

```py
import json
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'testspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        broker_ids = ['2713535', '1234456', '2134234']
        for broker_id in broker_ids:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=f'https://brokercheck.finra.org/individual/summary/{broker_id}',
                meta={
                    'broker_id': broker_id
                }
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        broker_id = response.meta.get('broker_id')
        # extract whatever content from the page you want here and save in broker item
        # then sends another request to get the name.
        broker = { }
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=f'https://api.brokercheck.finra.org/search/individual/{broker_id}?hl=true&nrows=12&query=&start=0&wt=json',
            callback=self.parse_name,
            meta={
                'broker': broker
            }
        )

    def parse_name(self, response):
        broker = response.meta.get('broker')
        json_data = json.loads(response.body)
        try:
            content = json_data['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']['content']
            content = json.loads(content)
            broker['first_name'] = content['basicInformation']['firstName']
            broker['middle_name'] = content['basicInformation']['middleName']
            broker['last_name'] = content['basicInformation']['lastName']
        except IndexError:
            print('something went wrong, could not find broker with that id')

        print(broker)
```

Comment: Very neat. I was able to use your spider to get additional information. Thanks! Can you tell me a way to loop through a range of broker_id?

Comment: I changed code to support multiple broker_ids, have a look